# send a message from content script to popup script

Tags: javascript, popup, message, send, content-script

i'm trying to send a message from my content script to my popup script because i need to use popup DOM when a page is loaded, here's what i tried :
contentScript.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        "action": "init"
    });
})
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "init") {
        alert('Initialisation demandée...')
    } else {
        alert('Je n\'ai pas compris')
    }
})
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Youtube color modifier",
    "description": "Change youtube colors",
    "version": "1.0",
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Youtube color modifier", 
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
   }]
}
```

Thank you for helping a noob :))

Answer (score 2):

If you have a content script, it will be run everytime you (re)load the page, assuming that the page you are visiting is registered in the manifest.json.

So instead of this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        "action": "init"
    });
})
```

simply try this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    "action": "init"
});
```